# Loop error adding while adding class to an element

Tags: php, pagination

I have a pagination on my website and for some reason the class 'active' is not being properly attributed because if I click on any page number above 4 they go to the respective page but the active class is not attributed.
Here's my code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <nav>
      <ul class="pager">
         <?php
         $totalPages = ceil($totalRows / $limit);
         $maxVisiblePages = 7; // Set the maximum number of page links to display (should be odd)
         $halfMaxVisiblePages = floor($maxVisiblePages / 2);
                
         // Calculate the starting and ending page numbers for limited pagination
         $startPage = max(1, $page - $halfMaxVisiblePages);
         $endPage = min($totalPages, $page + $halfMaxVisiblePages);
                
         // Adjust the starting page number if the ending page exceeds the total pages
         if ($endPage - $startPage + 1 < $maxVisiblePages) {
            $startPage = max(1, $endPage - $maxVisiblePages + 1);
         }

         if ($page > 1) {
            echo '<li class="pager__item pager__item--prev">
               <a class="pager__link" href="?page=' . ($page - 1) . '">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="8" height="12" viewbox="0 0 8 12">
                     <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                        <path fill="#33313C" d="M7.41 1.41L6 0 0 6l6 6 1.41-1.41L2.83 6z"></path>
                     </g>
                  </svg>
               </a>
            </li>';
         } else {
            echo '<li class="pager__item pager__item--prev">
               <a class="pager__link dis" href="?page=' . ($page - 1) . '">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="8" height="12" viewbox="0 0 8 12">
                     <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                        <path fill="#c4c4c4" d="M7.41 1.41L6 0 0 6l6 6 1.41-1.41L2.83 6z"></path>
                     </g>
                  </svg>
               </a>
            </li>';
         }

         // Loop through all the page numbers
         for ($i = $startPage; $i <= $endPage; $i++) {
            $isActive = ($i === $page) ? 'active' : '';
            echo '<li class="pager__item"><a class="pager__link ' . $isActive . '" href="?page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a></li>';
         }

         if ($page < $totalPages) {
            echo '<li class="pager__item pager__item--next">
               <a class="pager__link" href="?page=' . ($page + 1) . '">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="8" height="12" viewbox="0 0 8 12">
                     <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                        <path fill="#33313C" d="M7.41 1.41L6 0 0 6l6 6 1.41-1.41L2.83 6z"></path>
                     </g>
                  </svg>
               </a>
              </li>';
         } else {
         echo '<li class="pager__item pager__item--next">
            <a class="pager__link dis" href="?page=' . ($page + 1) . '">
               <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="8" height="12" viewbox="0 0 8 12">
                  <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                     <path fill="#c4c4c4" d="M7.41 1.41L6 0 0 6l6 6 1.41-1.41L2.83 6z"></path>
                  </g>
               </svg>
            </a>
           </li>';
         }
         ?>
      </ul> 
   </nav>
</div>
```

At this point I really can't figure what is causing this, I have tried multiple things but none of them work. Although I suspect that the issue may be related to the $startPage and $endPage but I am not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$halfMaxVisiblePages` is of type float, which means that `$startPage` and therefore `$i` can either be integer when it's 1, or a float when it's higher than that.

This is because of the use of different types within `$startPage = max(1, $page - $halfMaxVisiblePages);`

So when `$page - $halfMaxVisiblePages` is > 1, it becomes a float.

Assuming that `$page` is an integer, then `($i === $page)` is not true when `$i` is a float, because the types are not identical.

You could make sure that `$halfMaxVisibilePages` is always an integer by changing:

```
$halfMaxVisiblePages = floor($maxVisiblePages / 2);
```

to:

```
$halfMaxVisiblePages = (int) floor($maxVisiblePages / 2);
```